# Read in XmlElement value by given name

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I need to read the below XmlElement and retrieve defined elements/fields, here is the Element:

```
<Response>
  <code>JH4KB2F68AC24310A</code>
  <returnCode>1</returnCode>
  <fields name="ACES_ASP_ID">5</fields>
  <fields name="ACES_BASE">31990</fields>
</Response>
```

I can retrieve the first 2 easily. Here is what I use to get the first field:

```
MyXmlElement.SelectSingleNode("//Response/code").InnerText
```

How to I get the value from:

```
<fields name="ACES_ASP_ID">5</fields>
```

I have tried formats like:

```
MyXmlElement.SelectSingleNode("//Response[fields='" + "ACES_ASP_ID" + "']/fields").InnerText
```

With no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this:

```
MyXmlElement.SelectSingleNode("//Response/fields[@name='ACES_ASP_ID']")
            .InnerText
```

Comment: tried it a few times with different fields and still get:   "expression must evaluate to a node-set"

Comment: figured it out... needed a space between name and equals... picky picky picky xml...

Comment: @Don: It works for me. Without a space. Check it [here](http://ideone.com/YYxlIS).

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for the value of the *attribute*. Your test `fields='" + "ACES_ASP_ID" + "'` matches an element `fields` with text content "ACES_ASP_ID".

So you should try something like: `//Response/fields[@name = 'ACES_ASP_ID']`